# TcpClient fails on web service method

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, proxy

I've got next problem - i tried to use external assembly in my web service method (Web service is worked in LAN). This external assembly in their own internals use TcpClient to access to external IP address. But unfortunally. Creation of TcpClient fails.

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was caught
>   Message=A socket operation has encountered a dead network xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
>   Source=System
>   ErrorCode=10050
>   NativeErrorCode=10050
>   StackTrace:
>   в System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)

Access to external network from LAN realize with proxy Microsoft ISA Server. From console application all works fine, but from web service method occurs exception :(
I tried to use next parameters in web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" >

    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\User" password="password"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://isa-server:8080/" bypassonlocal="True" usesystemdefault="True"  />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

But also unfortunally. It strange, because request from WebRequest class executed in a normal manner. Problem exactly in TcpClient class.

```
 [WebMethod]
        public string Test()
        {
            // This code works fine
            var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.ru");
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Debug.Assert(response.StatusDescription.ToUpper() == "OK");
            // But this rise exception
            var a = new TcpClient("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", XXX).GetStream().CanRead;
        }
```

I also tried manual impersonalization in web service method, but also no result

```
new WindowsIdentity(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(true).Token).Impersonate();
```

Can anybody help me? May be problem in ISA proxy server incorrect parameters? I watched ISA server logs, it seems reguest from web service methods doesn't even get into proxy server. May be someone faced with the same challenge. Thanks in advance and sorry for my incorrect english!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slash from proxy address like following

```
<proxy proxyaddress="http://isa-server:8080"
```